# Proxy имеют такую же функцию как в VPN?

Tags: proxy, vpn

например при подключении к VPN, мы фактически получаем доступ к локальной сети  компьютера. например так можно подключиться к рабочей сети и использовать удаленный доступ к компьютеру, передавать на него файлы. Умеет ли так прокси?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "прокси" ? Если какой нибудь socks то он как раз для этого и предназначен, позволяет пробросить произвольные соединения. А обращены они наружу или внутрь защищенного периметра - это уже отдельный вопрос. Все что во вне почему то принято называть прокси, а все что внутрь - vpn (Я конечно сильно утрирую, это не является каким либо принятым обозначением)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю тут все зависит от цели:

1. Объединение двух сетей для обмена трафиком
2. Подключение к какой-то сети одного удаленного компьютера для работы в этой сети
3. Доступ к интернету через другую сеть с целью обхода ограничений местного оператора
4. Доступ к интернету через другую сеть с целью сокрытия данных о себе

Так вот VPN может решить (худо-бедно) все эти задачи, а proxy может решить только задачи 3 и 4 из этого списка.

p.s.: список конечно же не полный и приведен, что бы показать, что хоть и имеют эти технологии общие решаемые задачи, но по сути они разные (@Mike правильно писал на счет наружу/внутрь)